# In chrome memory snapshot, what does the number next to constructor mean?

Tags: google-chrome-devtools, devtools

[image]

I took a memory snapshot of my app (react, mobx, threejs). What exactly does the number 'x4' next to 'Game' mean - that 4 were made, or 4 are alive right now?

Comment: Please ask your second question in a separate thread, so future learners can find it easier.